# Cookies in MS Teams Tab application

Tags: microsoft-teams

I've been trying to work out authenticating users into my app, which is running inside a MS Teams Tab application, and I'm having issues in mobile.

To authorize requests in the application, we just need to have a cookie in place that the server sets when the user authenticates. So for this to work inside Microsoft Teams, I've been trying to just send the token to the iframe and set the cookie. Everything works pretty well on web and desktop, but on mobile (I've tested only with iOS so cannot really tell about Android), the cookie doesn't work at all.

I've tried to set some test cookies and read them, and it doesn't work. So my question is if there is a way to work with cookies in mobile? Is it an issue on my end or has it been disabled in the web view that loads the tab? Is there a way around it or any suggestion that would help solve my problem?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Why are you doing this by hand, and not just using MSAL? There are plenty of examples/samples on how to do this, that will work on desktop+mobile.

Comment: I'm doing it this way because it seemed the most straightforward. We only needed to authenticate users against our own application, so they can access authorized data. Right now the flow is fairly simple, the only thing failing is the cookie in mobile.
Going the AAD / MSAL route seemed much more complicated / time consuming.

Comment: Do you have an Azure-registered Application? You can use that to do your own app authentication, but it means you can plug into a lot of other capabilities, including Teams SSO

Comment: Yeah I understand. I just didn't want to switch implementations at this point since it's working well in web, desktop and android. I'm just looking for a definitive answer about cookies in iOS so I stop wasting time.
But thanks for the suggestion, I'll explore that option if this ends up being a dead end.

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution here? I am facing a similar scenario where authentication with my server is based on a cookie.